# How can I lookup into field in the array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "label" : "alex",
    "children" : [
        {
            "id" : "rJqS8aW-W"
        },
        {
            "id" : "SkF8UaW-W"
        }
    ],
}
{
    "label" : "felix",
    "id" : "rJqS8aW-W",
    "children" : [
        {
            "id" : "S1gcBUT---"
        },
        {
            "id" : "r1ltUUpZbb"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "label" : "tom",
    "id" : "SkF8UaW-W",
    "children" : [
        {
            "id" : "S1gcBUT---"
        },
        {
            "id" : "r1ltUUpZbb"
        }
    ]
}
....
```

What I want to do is, replace id fields with the documents.

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "label" : "alex",
    "children" : [
        {
            "id" : "rJqS8aW-W"
        },
        {
            "id" : "SkF8UaW-W"
        }
    ],
    details: [
        {
            "label" : "felix",
            "id" : "rJqS8aW-W",
            "children" : [
                {
                    "id" : "S1gcBUT---"
                },
                {
                    "id" : "r1ltUUpZbb"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label" : "tom",
            "id" : "SkF8UaW-W",
            "children" : [
                {
                    "id" : "S1gcBUT---"
                },
                {
                    "id" : "r1ltUUpZbb"
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
...
```

To be able to achieve this, I wrote;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {from: "collection" , localField: "children.id", foreignField: "id", as: "details"}}
])
```

But it doesn't return as I expect. Can't we use `$lookup` with arrays? I mean I want to search based on a field in the array.

edit:

some modifications like,

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
        {$lookup: {from: "collection" , localField: "$children.id", foreignField: "id", as: "details"}}
    ])
```

or

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
        {$lookup: {from: "collection" , localField: "children.$.id", foreignField: "id", as: "details"}}
    ])
```

also throws error.

What should I do? `flat`ting the `children` id field and than `$lookup`?

Comment: If all you are asking for is "replacing" the "children" then use `"children"` in the argument to `as`. Even says so in the documentation.

Comment: I want to get the details of children's which is included in the children array. for `alex` it includes 2 children, felix and tom.

Comment: The problem I see though is that you are "joining" to the same collection as in an "object graph". `$lookup` will not do this recursively, and if you are expecting recursion you should explain to what purpose as there may be a better solution to what you want to do.

Comment: Is my purpose not clear? I want to get the details of documents in the children array.

Comment: You want it to "recursively load" down all children. Yes that is understood. I just told you that **cannot** happen. Do you understand? At the same time I am asking you  *"Why do you **need** this?"* If it's just an exercise to see it happen then it's not going to work. If you actually explained what you intend to use this "hierarchy graph" for, then we might be able to point you to a solution. But `$lookup` does not do what you are asking.

Comment: Ok. I get it now, thank you for the explanation. Why do I need this? I need to find the hierarchy between the people and their children actually. I should list the connections and know whose children is who's from top.

Comment: [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/)